# Drag and drop image from wpf application to uwp application

Tags: image, uwp, drag-and-drop, uwp-xaml, drop

I am trying to drag an image from WPF application to UWP application but getting this error
"invalid formatetc structure (exception from hresult: 0x80040064 (dv_e_formatetc)) in  GetStorageItemsAsync method"

public async void OnFileDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

```
        List<StorageFile> dropFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            var isShow2GBMessage = false;
            var isShowEXEerrorMessage = false;
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var appFile in items.OfType<StorageFile>())
                {
                    BasicProperties filesize = await appFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                    var fileSize = filesize.Size;
                    CheckAndAddFiles(dropFiles, ref isShow2GBMessage, ref isShowEXEerrorMessage, appFile, fileSize);
                }
            }
            UploadFiles(dropFiles);
        }
    }
```

When I drag the image it is getting copied into a folder but how do I get the path address using DragEventArgs?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that, currently there is not such api  could drag and drop item between cross platforms. if you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub.

Comment: Can we copy the image path to the clipboard while dragging it and then at the drop-side if we can fetch it from the clipboard?

Comment: You could copy the file path while dragging, but drag item does not allow drop in uwp platform, I'm afraid the drop event will not be triggered.

Comment: No, drop event is getting triggered and I am able to fetch the files but sometimes it giving access denied error while copying data from the clipboard. I am not able to get the exact reason behind it.

Comment: If you could get file path please add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability then use windows storage api to access file for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).